# Is there a way to follow particular authors on arxiv?

Tags: arxiv, tools

I have googled and it is possible to create rss feeds for categories; nothing about rss feeds for authors.

Is there a way to automatically follow a large number of authors on arxiv?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/help/author_identifiers See the line about atom feeds for instructions on following one author.  If you have all the identifiers, you can manually follow all the authors.  Automating that is not really an ArXiv problem.

Comment: In general (for other types of web updates, I mean) I have had pretty good luck with google alerts and mention.com.

Comment: You can also follow RSS feeds in Thunderbird for example and just filter for the names you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Go to https://arxiv.org/search/ and search the author name (choose author name from the pull down menu on the right).

---

*Original deprecated method:*

Yes. It seems to be a link of the following form:

```
http://arxiv.org:443/find/math/1/au:+***AuthorIDHere***/0/1/0/all/0/1
```

Comment: Three comments in one: (1.) The search interface used here is deprecated. (2.) Why "http://arxiv.org:443" and not "https://arxiv.org"? (3.) I couldn't get this to work because it wasn't clear to me where to find an author's ID.

Comment: Why ":443"? Answer: I don't know. I have simply stated a solution. I don't have an explanation why it works.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could you give an example with an author ID so I understand how this works? Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I am indeed unable at the moment to provide a way to find authors id.

Comment: Thanks! That said, I don't see any RSS feed on the result page for a search, so I'm not sure that simply using the search interface answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

If the author has an ORCID ID, you can use something of the form:

https://arxiv.org/a/0000-0002-7970-7855.atom2

If the author has an arXiv ID, you can use:

http://arxiv.org/a/warner_s_1.atom2

Comment: How would I find out whether an author has an arXiv ID?

Comment: @Kvothe: Good question, I don't know -- I guess this could be asked to arXiv support

Answer (score 2):

The [arXiv API](https://arxiv.org/help/api/user-manual) can be used to return search query results in Atom format which should be readable by most RSS clients. For example, to follow "Author Name" you can add a feed to your RSS client by giving it the following url:

```
http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=au:"Author+Name"+OR+au:"A+Name"&sortBy=submittedDate&sortOrder=descending&max_results=100
```

The generic HTTP syntax is `http://export.arxiv.org/api/{method name}?{parameters}`. To break it down:

- `http://export.arxiv.org/api/` is the arXiv API endpoint.
- `query` is the method we call to search
- the `search_query` parameter specifies what to search for and where

  - `au:` says to search the author field
  - `+` is a space
  - `OR` is a boolean operator. Be sure you include all possible permutations of First Name (full or initial), Middle Name (full, initial, or absent), and Last Name to make sure you don't miss anything. You can also use this to combine multiple authors into a single feed, and you can use parentheses to build more complex boolean statements.
- `&` separates parameters
- `sortBy=submittedDate` and `sortOrder=descending` are also important to get the most recently submitted papers, and you may also want to specify `max_results`.

See [Details of Query Construction](https://arxiv.org/help/api/user-manual#query_details) in the appendix of the arXiv API spec.

---

I've tested this with [Feedly](https://feedly.com/) and I'm able to get feeds with the latest articles by the authors I'm looking for. The results depend on the quality of your search query.

P.S. You can use [this online tool](https://validator.w3.org/feed/) to validate that your url is in fact returning an RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Arxiv Sanity has this feature.

http://www.arxiv-sanity.com/

Comment: Actually, it doesn't.  It allows following 'friends', but you have to invite them first and have them accept.

Comment: It is possible to search by name, but it appears that quoted strings do not work and you can't require that the name be an author.

Answer (score 0):

If the author has a google scholar profile, then there is a button to "follow them" next to their profile and by doing this you can get email notification whenever they publish a new article or(and) get cited. But no idea on whether it can be done automatically.

Comment: An author can have multiple e-mails.

Comment: @Nobody, I edited my answer to avoid confusion. It doesn't matter how many e-mails they have as long as they have a google scholar profile.

Comment: This approach also relies on the author keeping their profile up to date, and on Google Scholar's indexing being timely.