# How to cite a paper as shortened first author name and year [Ste2002]?

Tags: citation-style, reference-managers

The way I'd like to cite papers in my work is 3 characters of the last name of the first author + year of publication without spaces, 'et al.' and comas.
I'd like to use Citavi, as it has convenient Word add-on, but I haven't found how to shorten last names there so far. After all, if it is possible in another program, I will give it a try.

Such citing style was chosen to enhance reading experience, as reader can relate to the cited paper much easily by the last name and the year of publication and trace it throughout the document. This style is yet shorter, than patterns officially available in Citavi.

Comment: Besides technical aspects. How a reader can trace what are you referring to?

Comment: Can’t you just manually assign the correct reference name? All citation tools should allow and remember this.

Comment: @Alchimista through context and of course bibliographic list

Comment: @eckes particularly in Citavi it is allowed to change fields only through available options, which don't include last name shortings

Comment: Yes but why not to use numbers than? Sorry but perhaps I misunderstand something. Why Ste2002 instead of a number ?

Comment: @MrCheatak ok, that sux

Comment: @Alchimista citation style is often defined by Organisation or publication

Comment: @Alchimista [Ste2002] gives much more information than [1], e.g., those familiar with the literature know that Ste means Stevenson whose 2002 paper is entitled XYZ.

Comment: Ok it never happened to me.  I did it as well for my own organising but never saw in book or paper. But I actually already know that is Ste2002 that I need to cite. Doesn't matter I was just curious where this is required ;) @user2768

Comment: @Alchimista I am using this citation in my diploma thesis

Comment: In that case I suggest you use a standard numbering. That citing is just useful to you as for you immediately get to think of a specific paper.  A reader won't feel that unless you are discussing a paper so that s/he get familiar to it as you are. But it is matter of taste, no doubt. It depends on how many papers you have to cite, how many are from Ste and how many are from 2002. All the best for you thesis!

Comment: @Alchimista  unless specific style is used in the institution, indeed its a matter of taste. I found it more readable and relatable to use year and shortened last names. In my work I'm citing more than 100 sources and some of them much more often than others. Thanks!

Comment: FYI: [Technical support: ration vs emotion](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4403/14341)

Comment: @Ooker according to your link, a would say ration should prevail, as this is not just about printing the document the right way, but more about using specific academic software for achieving better reading experience. I did not point out reasons for using such style, but it was correctly noticed by user2768.

Comment: Yes, your question sparks another interest in me to follow up the problem. Because ironically your question does make me feel it's off-topic, while I did ask a very similar question and felt that having it closed was a, well, irrational decision. Anyway, I think your appeal on the close should be more accessible, like in the bottom of the question, or in a meta post, or in mod flag.

Comment: @Ooker Well, I guess then, my question is on the very border.

Comment: One of the close votes is mine, my rational: How to use [Ste2002] or [1] is off-topic, it's a LaTeX, Word, etc. problem. Why to use [Ste2002] rather than [1] is on-topic. (There's already a stackexchange site dedicated to LateX.)

Comment: @user2768 as I see it, it comes down to the usage of tools, that are directly connected with academic. Not some distant program, that puts text in a right way.

Comment: @MrCheatak I'm not sure where you're drawing the line. Personally, I consider all discussion of LaTeX off-topic, because there is a stackexchange dedicated to the topic. I'm sure similar forums exist for Word.

Comment: @user2768 this topic is not dedicated to LaTeX or Word, but may rather touch their functionality. Solution may appear in any other software, which I hope will be found with Citavi, as I'm more familiar with it.

Comment: @MrCheatak Your question boils down to how different software packages handle citations. That's a software question

Comment: @user2768 As I see it, paper publication requires knowledge of corresponding software dedicated to that. So knowing the solution using tools, that are created for academical purposes is still academic.

Comment: @user2768 do you think your rational contradict with the community rational that technical support is on-topic? I know this is absurd, but take a look at this question and you will see more: [Is there a way to follow particular authors on arxiv?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/81831/14341)

Comment: @Ooker I don't make the rules, I follow them. If you don't like them, then change them. (In this particular instance, forums for these questions already exist and those forums are far better qualified to provide an answer.)

Answer (score 2):

There's an easier LaTeX solution (compared to another [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/123328/22768)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}

First statement \cite{gascuel97}, and a second statement \cite{sokal58}.

\bibliographystyle{alpha}  %Sets [Ste2002] bibligraphy style
\bibliography{sample}      %Imports bibliography file

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there an advantage other than less lines of code? Biblatex is much more powerful and intended to replace Bibtex (used in your answer). See for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/what-is-the-difference-between-bibtex-and-biblatex

Comment: _Fewer lines of code_ wins it for me, beyond that advantages include: easier to remember/understand, fewer dependencies, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use LaTeX instead of word, there is a very simple solution to achieve something close to what you want. The relevant command is to specify the "alphabetic" style, when loading the biblatex package. `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, citestyle=alphabetic]{biblatex}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
citestyle=alphabetic
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sample.bib} %Imports bibliography file

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

First statement \cite{gascuel97}, and a second statement \cite{sokal58}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: the resulting citation styles]

Comment: I guess I'll have to remaster the work into LaTeX?

Comment: There might be a solution in Word, but I can't help with that. Maybe someone else has an answer for you before you commit to using LaTeX.

Comment: I'd definitely try LaTeX if had a little bit more time. Now it would be faster to type everything manually in Word